# Custom alpha brush

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I've created this custom brush and my goal is to have a fairly deep cut in the middle, preferably below geometry where I'm sculpting and have the two lines on either side sticking out but only a little bit to simulate a sort of leather seam. Any advice on this?

Thanks

[image]

[image: I want to achieve something similar to the second vertical stitching from the left (without visible stitches]

Comment: Can you add a picture of where the tool is now, and what kind of sculpt you want to achieve. Otherwise the question is too broad/unclear.

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear I've added an image and I'm tring to replicatenthe second vertical line from the left (witho visible stitching) thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty simple. Don't have any shades of gray that are bright so that it only is a recess and the lines don't stick out.

Comment: It does, doesn't it? That's how I thought it worked, but then I end up without any cut into the geometry it's just a flat brush. What it's starting to look like to me is that when you have an additive brush blender sees black as zero height and white as 100% hight and with a subtractive brush I don't even know what it's doing but an inverted image doesn't seem to yield the opposite result with a subtractive brush.

Comment: hmm, that's interesting. I haven't experimented with subtractive or additive brushes yet, sorry.